# Is $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,\pi)$ open

Tags: general-topology

Is the set $A=[0,\pi) \cap \mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}$ open in $\mathbb{Q}$?

How can i solve this.

Comment: it is closed‌‌.

Comment: @Ilya the question is asking whether the set is open in $\mathbb Q$, not $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 7):

HINT: $0\in A$; does $A$ contain an open neighborhood about $0$?